# How to blur or to add transparency to fontawesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap and fontawesome. I've got a bullet list like that:

```
<ul class="fa-ul lead">
    <li class="m"><i class="fa-li fa fa-2x fa-check"></i><p>Text.</p></li>
    <li class="m"><i class="fa-li fa fa-2x fa-check"></i><p>Text.</p></li>
    <li class="m"><i class="fa-li fa fa-2x fa-check"></i><p>Text.</p></li>
    <li class="m"><i class="fa-li fa fa-2x fa-check"></i><p>Text.</p></li>  
</ul>
```

The icons `fa` produced a bit too rich and vivid. I want to add a bit transparency or something to make them looking not so much vivid. Is there any way I can do that without any `custom css`?

**UPDATED:**
By saying `custom css` I meant that may be there is some bootstrap or fontawesome css classes already exists in order to do that. So I was looking for css solution.

Comment: Why no custom css? Using opacity or an rgba color is probably the way to go.

Comment: I've removed the `twitter-bootstrap` tag as this question isn't related to it.

Comment: This is the *reason* css exists. Why don't you want to use the exact thing that controls how elements are displayed/styled on a page?

Comment: `text-secondary`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated on Font Awesome's homepage:

> Font Awesome gives you scalable vector icons that can instantly be customized — size, color, drop shadow, and anything that can be done with the power of CSS.

There's absolutely no reason *not* to use CSS, so ignoring your requirement of not using CSS I'm going to give you a CSS solution anyway and suggest you use this instead of the non-CSS solution I've also provided:

### CSS Solution

Font Awesome icons are characters contained within a font. This makes them regular text, allowing you to style the characters as you would regular text.

```css
.fa-li.fa.fa-2x.fa-check {
    opacity: 0.75;                /* Opacity (Transparency) */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);   /* RGBA Color (Alternative Transparency) */
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);    /* Blur */
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

A better solution might just be to change the colour of your icons to something less prominent:

```css
.fa-li.fa.fa-2x.fa-check {
    color: #444;
}
```

### Non-CSS Solution

If you *really* want a non-CSS solution, like you've stated in the question, one thing you could do is save the relevant icon as an image and play around with it in any picture editing software to apply the effect you're looking for. Then, instead of adding the icon in using the provided Font Awesome CSS, you could upload the image to your server and include it as an `img` element:

```
<img src="path/to/my-modified-fa-icon.png" alt="fa-check" />
```

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
.fa{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Thats assuming you want all fa icons a little 'see through' you could of course always change the colour too, so maybe use grey instead of black

```
.fa{
    color:#878787;
}
```

If you only want to style this lists fa's try

```
.m .fa{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

or if you are using sass/less

```
.m{
    .fa{
        opacity:0.5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick a dark shade that's fitting your UI from [here](http://www.0to255.com/ddd) and use it like below.
If for example you selected the color #ddd, add the below style to your CSS

```
ul.lead .fa{
    color: #ddd
}
```